# Farm Admin - but unable to iterate thru sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, access-denied

I am in the Farm Admin group (thru CA) and have DB owner access to WSS_Content and SharePoint_Config database. I am running following powershell. It runs fine  but throwing "Access is Denied" when it hits one of the site. I checked the $web thru browser and I can see the sites and noticed there are no sub sites.

```
foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites)
{       
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 
    {
```

Comment: did you try to add the farm admin account into Policy of Web App with full control?

Comment: great, i added that as answer...if you marked it and up vote then others will get benefits...and some points for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your Farm admin Account into the Policy Web App and then try to run your script.

Sometime unique permission cause this issue but if Farm admin account is in policy for web app with full control then it will work.